# What is script tag's origin when it's from a third party?

Tags: javascript, cookies

On MDN in document.cookie domain section it says

> If not specified, this defaults to the host portion of the current document location

> The domain must match the domain of the JavaScript origin. Setting cookies to foreign domains will be silently ignored. [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie#:%7E:text=The%20domain%20must)

Now if you load a third party script, meaning, it's from `xyz.com` and not `yourdomain.com`, and this loaded script sets a cookie and doesn't specify a domain. Then it'd be setting a cookie on `yourdomain.com`. However, the 2nd rules says the domain must match script origin. The origin of script is `xyz.com` and it's setting cookie on domain `yourdomain.com`.

Is this a contradiction? Am I misunderstanding something?

I've confirmed, yes, third party scripts can in-fact modify cookie of the host page.

Answer (score 4):

A cookie set with an HTTP `Set-Cookie` header will be set based on the URL of resource being requested (regardless of if that resource is an HTML document, a script, an image, or something else).

A cookie set with client-side JS (`document.cookie`) will be set based on the URL of the HTML document the script is running it (even if the JS was loaded with a `src` attribute pointing at a different hostname).

The script origin is the HTML document hosting the script, not the URL of the script.

Comment: Script origin is the HTML document hosting the script...hmmmm sounds questionable but only that that make it all work

Comment: is there a source for this, why wont script origin be where the script was loaded from?